# ArrayList unintentionally appended at the end of GSON String each time I rotate the screen

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-sharedpreferences, gson

I am trying to save a custom class containing `ArrayLists` to `SharedPreferences` using GSON. Each time I rotate the screen, the activity starts over and the string generated by gson seems to append the `ArrayList` to the previous string, instead of replacing it.

The `SimpleUserValues` class is just a class to store user info, with an empty constructor and private `ArrayLists` together with their corresponding setters and getters.

The code in my activity is as follows:

```
SimpleUserValues simpleUserValues = SimpleUserValues.newInstance();
simpleUserValues.setTheBooleans(userValues.getTheBooleans());

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type classType = new TypeToken<SimpleUserValues>() {
}.getType();
String insertedJSON = gson.toJson(simpleUserValues, classType);

if (getSharedPreferences(myAppKey, MODE_PRIVATE).contains("JSON")) {
    Log.e("insertedJSON ", getSharedPreferences(myAppKey, MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString("JSON", ""));
    getSharedPreferences(myAppKey, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove("JSON")
            .commit();
    getSharedPreferences(myAppKey, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putString("JSON", insertedJSON).commit();
} else {
    getSharedPreferences(myAppKey, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putString("JSON", insertedJSON).commit();
}
```

The output I see from Log.e is like this:

```
insertedJSON﹕ {"theBooleans":[true,true,true,true,true,true],...
insertedJSON﹕ {"theBooleans":[true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true],...
insertedJSON﹕ {"theBooleans":[true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true],...
insertedJSON﹕ {"theBooleans":[true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true],...
```

Any ideas / known issues ? I am even deleting the previously saved string before writing, so I cannot understand how this appending is coming from. The input into SimpleUserValues is always the same. Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: here it is the custom class SimpleUserValues:

```
public class SimpleUserValues {


    private int theCurrentFragment;
    private int theCurrentGraph;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> theBooleans;
    private ArrayList<Integer> theIntegers;



    public SimpleUserValues() {
    }

    public static SimpleUserValues newInstance(){
        return new SimpleUserValues();
    }

    public ArrayList<Boolean> getTheBooleans() {
        return theBooleans;
    }

    public void setTheBooleans(ArrayList<Boolean> theBooleans_) {
        theBooleans = theBooleans_;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getTheIntegers() {
        return theIntegers;
    }

    public void setTheIntegers(ArrayList<Integer> theIntegers_) {
        theIntegers = theIntegers_;
    }

    public int getTheCurrentFragment() {
        return theCurrentFragment;
    }

    public void setTheCurrentFragment(int theCurrentFragment_) {
        theCurrentFragment = theCurrentFragment_;
    }

    public int getTheCurrentGraph() {
        return theCurrentGraph;
    }

    public void setTheCurrentGraph(int theCurrentGraph_) {
        theCurrentGraph = theCurrentGraph_;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the code for your `UserValues`/`SimpleUserValues`(?) classes. Shared preferences do not get appended so I think the issue might be in there. You haven't given enough code to see where your problem is at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bug in the arrays I was saving, adding more rows instead of replacing. Oops. Thanks @Kane for your comment